# Difference between google-maps-services and play-services-maps

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services, google-maps-android-api-2

I found two libraries in Android Studio's Add a library in Module settings.
What is difference between these two libraries:

```
com.google.maps:google-maps-services
```

and

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps
```

Where are these used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** `com.google.maps:google-maps-services`

This is the **Google Maps Web Services**, and consists of tools for things requiring geographic data like directions or distance. It is defined in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/web-services/overview#Services) as follows:

> The Google Maps web services are a collection of HTTP interfaces to
>   Google services providing geographic data for your maps applications.

**2.** `com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps`

This library, on the other hand, allows for the interaction with a physical map, including things like event listening, camera angle and location, map type, etc. You can refer to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/package-summary) for its specific functionalities.

I hope this answered your question!